Реверс функции vsprintf_s
Есть примерно такой кусок кода:
void  func(char* param_1, ...)
{  
    va_list args;
    int cnt;
    int iVar2;
    char* _DstBuf;        
    va_start(args, param_1);
    iVar2 = _vscprintf(param_1, args);
    if (-1 < iVar2) {
        _DstBuf = malloc(iVar2 * sizeof(char));
         int cnt;           
       
        cnt = vsprintf_s(buffer, iVar2 + 1, "%019I64d", args);
        va_end(args);        
    }  
   
    return(cnt);
}

На вход передается 2 указателя на переменные. В результате в буфер записывается строка. В моем случае в виде 19-значного числа. Есть ли возможность сделать реверс? Т.е. есть ли такая функция, куда я мог бы передать это 19-значное число и спецификатор формата "%019I64d", а на выходе получить 2 нужных мне числа? Смотрел в сторону vsscanf_s, но что-то не получается.

Я правильно понял, что вы хотите передать в функцию строку с цифрами и формат, а получить количество цифр в строке и значение числа в int64_t ?

@avp Не совсем. Функция vsprintf_s принимает формат(в данном случае "%019I64d") и набор переменных(точнее указатели на переменные. В моем случае их две. Это может быть два числа, либо строки). И как результат записывает в буфер 19-значное число/строку(тут не важно). Мне нужно произвести реверс. Т.е. нужна такая функция куда я бы передал содержимое этого буфера и формат(в данном случае "%019I64d"), и на выходе получил бы значения этих двух переменных.

Каких 2-х конкретно? Не считая адреса буфера для размещения результата и формата вы передаете в vsprintf одну переменную типа int64_t (в соответствии с форматом I64d). Например -- vsprintf(buf, "%I64d", v); (я опустил спецификатор ширины поля и символа заполнителя). Очевидно, что из символов буфера (после вызова vsprintf) можно получить v (это одна переменная). О какой второй переменной (какое значение в ней должно получиться) вы говорите?

@avp Да. Получается только одну переменную. Ошибся. Я немного покопался. В документации сказано что _vscprintf отдает только число символов в строке. Но судя по дампу, после ее вызова, в память записывается форматированная строка/число длиной в 19 символов. Как понимаю вызывается _vscprintf("%019I64d", args); и в память записывается строка. У меня на руках уже есть эта строка, если конкретнее "5519383994447167858". И мне вот нужно понять что передается в _vscprintf чтобы получился такой результат.

Такой результат (в буфере) вы получите при вызове sprintf/vsprintf, а (чисто виндовая) функция _vscprintf  вернет количество байт в буфере, которые были бы записаны в буфер sprintf/vsprintf с теми же аргументами, т.е. это аналог posix функции vsprint(NULL, format, arg_list). Если вы хотите получить только результат в буфере, то sprintf(buf, "%019I64d", 5519383994447167858); произведет его. Ну, т.е. какую-то такую функцию f(char *buf, char *fmt, ...), которая вызывает vprintf(buf, fmt, arg_list); вызвали как f(buf, "%019I64d", 5519383994447167858);

@avp Не совсем понял. ЧТобы получить 5519383994447167858 нужно вызвать функцию и передать ей 5519383994447167858? Просто я вижу что вызывается именно _vscprintf и только после этого в памяти откуда-то появляется 5519383994447167858. До этого ничего похожего нет.

Если у вас есть код откуда вызывается func() (из текста вопроса), то возможно получится лучше. Пока же могу сказать, что эта  функция, вызывая _vscprintf(param_1, args) (тут param_1 используется как формат) получает размер вывода, который будет получен при вызове vsprintf(buf, param_1, args). Затем она выделяет память достаточного размера под такой вывод. А вот потом почему-то в вызове vsprintf_s(...) с теми же args используется другой формат (в соответствии с ним берется первый элемент списка args, который д.б. переменной типа uint64_t).

Вот только после этого вызова (а не сразу после вызова _vscprintf) в буфере появляется 5519383994447167858 (очевидно это значение первого элемента args). Не знаю, насколько я помог в решении вашего вопроса, но дело обстоит как-то так.

@avp В _vscprintf и vsprintf_s передается один формат "%019I64d". Это я заменил для наглядности. Я просто дебажу программу через x64dbg. И именно сразу после вызова _vscprintf в памяти уже появляется запись 5519383994447167858. Но в момент вызова ее нет нигде(я делаю поиск по полному дампу памяти). По документации _vscprintf  принимается список агрументов, они могут склеиваться как-то? Если мы передадим например несколько аргументов а-ля 55 19 38 то они в результате склеятся в 551938 или это невозможно?

@avp В общем вроде примерно понял в чем дело. Просто значение хранится двумя кусками в памяти и вычисляется дейстительно до вызова функции
